# need help on #include doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c++, string, include

So I have a class called HPStack and I have to include it in my main class etc. However I get a "In File included from" error, what could be causing this?

Also my string objects also have errors I have have no idea why, the error is: "Unable to identifier string".

I'm new the C++ so any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

The error I am getting (I think) are these:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before "namespace"
error: expected `,' or `;' before "namespace"
error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
error: `<type error>' is not a namespace
```

Im not sure what I am missing but that isn't telling me much.

Here is my code: The class.h file.

```
#ifndef HPSTACK_H
#define HPSTACK_H

class HPStack {
public:
    HPStack();



    void push(double);
    double pop();
    double peek();



private:
    double register_[4];

}

#endif
```

The class.cpp file.

```
#include "HPStack.h"
#include <cstdlib>



HPStack::HPStack() : register_{}{
}

double HPStack::push(double x) {

    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (isdigit(register_[i])) {

            register_[i] = register_[i + 1];
        }
        register_[0] = x;
    }
}

double HPStack::pop() {

    return register_[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        register_[i] = register_[i + 1];
    }
}

double HPStack::peek() {

    return register_[0];
}
```

And my main file:

```
#include "HPStack.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    HPStack stack;
    string line;

    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        stringstream expression(line);
        string token;
        while (expression >> token) {
            if (isdigit(token[0])) {
                stack.push(atof(token.data()));
            } else if (token == "+") {
                double x = stack.pop();
                double y = stack.pop();
                double z = (y + x);
                stack.push(z);
            }
        }
        cout << stack.peek();
    }
```

Comment: What's the full error and what line is it on.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [faq]. You'll get a badge (c:

Comment: Please note that `register_ - 2` returns a pointer to before the array.

Comment: The errors are on the following lines the #include "HPStack.h" line the error reads "In file included from main.cpp:2:"  The second error I think occurs when I go to create a string object. and I get "Unable to identifier string".

Comment: The "in file included from..." part of the error message is telling you **how** you got the code that's causing the error. The actual error message comes **before** that. It probably contains the word "error".

Comment: I added the errors I am still receiving after fixing the errors that were pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

The error is, I'm guessing, because of this line:

```
double register_[4] = {};
```

You can not initialize class members when declaring them.

If your compiler is new enough to support C++11 features, you can use an initializer list with the constructor:

```
HPStack::HPStack() 
    : register_{}
{
}
```

Otherwise you have to initialize the array manually in the constructor.

---

And as I noted in a comment, using `register_ - 2` makes no sense as it returns a pointer so the index variable `i` will be *way* beyond the end of the array.

And using `register_ - 1` as the condition in the `pop` loop makes even less sense, as it will always be non-zero and therefore always true and the loop will loop forever.

Comment: OKay so what could I use instead of the regidter_-2 to be able to loop through the array? Also I fixed the intializing in the header.

Comment: @user2333446 It depends on what you want to do, it's not quite obvious to me. But since you use `i` as an index into an array with four entries it has to be between `0` and `3` (inclusive).

Comment: I just swapped out the old register_-1 with 3 and register_-2 with 2, I think that should work...

Comment: I added the errors I am still recieving after fixing the errors that were pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `;` at the end of the class definition:

```
class HPStack {
    ...
};  // <== This semicolon is required
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I missed that. also it is saying it is "unable to resolve identifier string" any idea why?